# Use Awk and Grep to find lines between two time in a log file

Tags: bash, awk, grep, gawk

I'm searching a log file to see if it contains a certain string between two different time. i.e. if `foo` exists between the lines that starts with the timestamp of `2016-11-10 06:45:00` and `2016-11-10 10:45:00` The `threshold` variable sets the time between, for example 240 would be 4 hours.

```
current="$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
threshold=240
dt_format="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
from="$(date -d "$threshold minutes ago" "$dt_format")"

if awk '$0 >= "$from" && $0 <= "$current"' /path/file.log | grep "foo"
then
   exit 0
else
   exit 1
fi
```

However I'm not sure why but when I pass `$from` and `$current` in the command line in the `if` statement, it's not actually reading it. It's as if I'm passing in garbage so it's not comparing the dates right and will return all the lines and exit 0.

But if I manually put in the dates in the `if` statement, i.e. `2016-11-10 06:45:00` as `from` and `2016-11-10 10:45:00` as `current` then it returns the correct lines that are in between those two dates and then I can use grep to check whether those lines contain `foo`.

I really don't understand why my code isn't working, and I can't manually put in the dates as I need to be able to check between two different time based on my needs by changing the `threshold` variable.

`2016-11-10 06:45:00` is how the timestamp is formatted in my log, starting in the beginning of each lines.

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: You don't need the `if ...; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi` construct: If you leave that out, your script will exit with grep's exit status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to have bash expand variables single quotes... run `s="string"; echo '$s'` and you'll see what I mean.

So this `'$0 >= "$from" && $0 <= "$current"'` Literally means those exact characters.  Probably not what you wanted.

"But that's the argument to awk"... Right so awk knows how to handle $0 and $1, so awk is properly expanding those.  But you were expecting awk to get `'$0 >= "some_time" && $0 <= "Some_other_time"'`  But it didn't!

So, the way you pass variables to awk is doing `some_variable="world"; awk -v my_variable=$some_variable 'BEGIN{print "hello", my_variable}'`

So you should have `if awk -v f="$from" -v c="$current" '$0 >= f && $0 <= c' /path/file.log | grep "foo"`

Check out http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ten-awk-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls/ This article actually has some good insight into neat things you can do with awk.  You *might* be able to use the "split file on patterns" here to reduce the amount of commands you use but either way you'll learn something about awk.

Comment: The variables "to" and "from" contain whitespace, so quoting is crucial: `awk -v from="$from" -v c="$current" ...`

Comment: Fixed answer to reflect @glenn